# Why can this premise not be inverted?

Tags: logic

I have the following two premises:

```
1) No writer is a politician.
2) Some journalists are politicians.
```

Now check this statement. Is it true or false?

```
a) No politicians are writers.
```

My solution text says that statement a) is not correct! But why? If there is a politician who is a writer, then premise 1) would be incorrect. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: What is the question that leads to a)?

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid [Syllogism in EIO form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Ferioque_(EIO-1)).

The conclusion must be:

> Some Journalist is not Writer.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks correct to me... The contrapositive of a true statement is true.

Your statement looks like $\neg p \to q$ (No writer is a politician). The contrapositive of this would be $\neg q \to p$ (No politician is a writer).

The solution text must be incorrect!

Comment: Thank you! The chapter has the title "Syllogisms". Maybe there are other rules?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: the conclusion follows from premise 1 alone: if no writer is a politician, then no politician is a writer.

There must have been a mistake.... probably as the author was creating this exercise, copying and pasting or modifying some other syllogism.